# Pandas csv reader does not recognize the delimeter

Tags: python, csv, pandas

This is a fragment of csv file:

```
"tac,""vendor"",""platform"",""type"""
"00100429,""PROTO"",""Proprietary"",""Phone"""
"00100430,""PROTO"",""Proprietary"",""Phone"""
"00100431,""PROTO"",""Proprietary"",""Phone"""
```

I read it with:

```
pd.read_csv("path/name.csv", sep=",")
```

But it returns a dataframe with **one merged column**:

```
    tac,"vendor","platform","type"
0   00100429,"PROTO","Proprietary","Phone"
1   00100430,"PROTO","Proprietary","Phone"
2   00100431,"PROTO","Proprietary","Phone"
3   00100432,"PROTO","Proprietary","Phone"
4   00100433,"PROTO","Proprietary","Phone"
5   00100434,"PROTO","Proprietary","Phone"
6   00100435,"PROTO","Proprietary","Phone
```

Obviously, i need all filed to be separated by ","

Comment: There are no `,` delimiters between lines. How is this file produced? Can you fix it at source as this is a bad format?

Comment: @roganjosh I don't know. But it recognizes lines successfully. It just fails to recognize commas, because of those quotes. And i don't know, how to get rid of them....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different `quotechar`

```
pd.read_csv("path/name.csv", quotechar="'") \
    .replace('"', '', regex=True).rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('"'))

        tac vendor     platform   type
0  00100429  PROTO  Proprietary  Phone
1  00100430  PROTO  Proprietary  Phone
2  00100431  PROTO  Proprietary  Phone
​
```